# What is the Formula for Prediction Interval in Multivariate Case?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, linear-model, prediction-interval

I am using linear model to do prediction, and I would like to calculate my prediction's prediction interval, which, when there is only one predictor, is

[image]

However, my model has three predictors. What is the formula for multivariate case?

I have been searching for a while, but I cannot find a formula for this.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+prediction+interval+formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is denoted by $\mathrm{MSE}$ in your formula is the residual mean square which some people, confusingly, call error mean square or even mean squared error$-$hence the abbreviation in your formula.
The residual mean square is an unbiased estimator of the (conditional) error or disturbance variance $\sigma^2$.
It is given by
$$
\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat y_i)^2}{n-k-1},
$$
where $k$ is the number of regressors. Note that we have $k=1$ in the simple linear regression model, and with three regressors (not counting the intercept) we have $k=3$.
The formula of the prediction interval for the future observation $y_h$ at location $\mathbf{x}_h={(1,x_{h1},\ldots,x_{hk})}^\top$ gets only slightly more complicated in the general case with $k$ regressors:
$$
\hat y_h\mp t_{(1-\alpha/2,\,n-k-1)}\times\sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2\times\left(1+\mathbf{x}_h^{\top}\left(\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{x}_h\right)},
$$
where $\hat y_h =\mathbf{x}_h^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$, $\mathbf{X}$ is the [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix), and $t_{(1-\alpha/2,\,n-k-1)}$ the  $(1-\alpha/2)$ quantile of the $t$-distribution with $n-k-1$ degrees of freedom.
For $k=1$ this reduces to the formula in your question if we identify the second entry of $\mathbf{x}_h={(1,x_{h1})}^\top$, i.e. $x_{h1}$, with $x_h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should we add $1/n$ in the square root on your second equation?

Comment: @user398843 No, $\sigma^2\left(x_h^{\top}\left(X^{\top}X\right)^{-1}x_h\right)$ is the variance of $\hat y_h$ and reduces to $\sigma^2  \left(1/n + \left(x_h-\bar x \right)^2 / \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar x\right)^2 \right)$ in the case of only one regressor.

Comment: And what if k >n?

Comment: @PascalIv Then $\mathbf X$ doesn't have full column rank and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ is not uniquely defined.